# Como evitar que se corte una tabla con varios tr

Tags: html, css

como puedo evitar que se corte una tabla que contiene varios tr
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla esta compuesta por tr

```
<table width="100%" name='page_table' >
<tr style="page-break-inside: avoid !important;">
                            
  <td style="background:#ccc;text-transform: uppercase;" colspan="8" class="text-center">
      <t t-esc="business_line['name']" />
   </td>
                            
    </tr>

<tr style="background:#1C4484;page-break-inside: avoid !important;">
                                <td style="width:5%;color:white" class="stilo7">
                                    <b>Nro</b>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:10%;color:white" class="stilo7">
                                    <b>CODIGO</b>
                                </td>
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

Como puedo evitar que se corte puesto que aparece el corte asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desearia que todo el contenido aparezca de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que se corta. La diferencia que veo es que en la segunda imagen se ve la cabecera de la tabla, a parte de que el html que has incluido no es la misma tabla.